# JavaFX ImageView from URL when clicking on button

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, fxml

I need to load a lot of images so instead of saving them in my computer I want to load them from an url. This is the code I have but it doesnt work, its not returning me any error but no image is being shown.

```
@FXML private ImageView pkmnImg;

@FXML
    void displayImg(MouseEvent event) {
        String imageSource = "http://github.com/PokeAPI/sprites/blob/master/sprites/pokemon/10.png";
        Image image = new Image(imageSource);
        pkmnImg.setImage(image);

    }
```

Is this code correct or should I change something?

Comment: `pkmnImg = new ImageView(image);` replace with `pkmnImg.setImage(image);`.

Comment: I tried it but its still not showing me any image, I also tried with different url but nothing happens, thanks anyway. EDIT: I tried with yet another url and now its working, so I need to figure out whats wrong with my url, thanks!

Comment: That means you have more mistakes somewhere else.

Comment: Its working with the third url i tried. I tried some random img from imgur, so thanks, now i know the issue is in the url

Comment: Probably you need to use the url for the raw data instead: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/10.png`

Comment: Yes, thats it, now it works!

Comment: Just to mention, `javafx.scene.image.Image` has an [`exception` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#exceptionProperty). If there is an error while loading the `Image` from the `URL` it usually sets the the property instead of throwing it out to the caller.